# JDK folder is missing in java version 1.8.0_362-b08 (for RHEL)

Tags: java, java-8, rhel, rhel7

I got only jre folder for below java version but not the jdk folder.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[AU\bhrbr2@abcdefd08 ~]$ cd /usr/lib/jvm

[AU\bhrbr2@abcdefd08 jvm]$ ls -lrt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 16 Jan 27 17:04 java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Jan 27 17:04 jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 27 17:04 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jan 27 17:04 jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 27 17:04 jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 27 17:07 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre

[AU\bhrbr2@abcdefd08 jvm]$ cd java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64

[AU\bhrbr2@abcdefd08 java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.362.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64]$ ls -lrt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 90 Jan 27 17:04 jre

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the JDK folder for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the required jdk from OpenLogic site.

https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads?field_java_parent_version_target_id=416&field_operating_system_target_id=426&field_architecture_target_id=391&field_java_package_target_id=All

But I want to just install jdk alone using yum/rpm command line in RHEL for same version (as I already have the jre) under the same directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Was this supposed to give additional context to your question? If so, please [edit] your question instead of posting an answer.